# adding 1 to an ArrayList item

Tags: java

I'm checking the frequency of the dice totals after 36 million rolls. I planned to make an arrayList and use it as a tally system when any of the 11 results came up.  How would I add 1 to one of the items in the list?

```
int die1, die2, dicetotal;

ArrayList<Integer> results = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
results.add(0); //for the 11th

for(int i = 0; i < 36000000; i++){
          die1 = (int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1
          die2 = (int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1
          dicetotal = die1 + die2;

          Switch (dicetotal){
                 case 2: results.set(0, CURRENT + 1);
                 ...
                 ...
                 ...

      }
```

Comment: Why an ArrayList and not just an `int[]` ?

Comment: idk, it's in the current chapter that I'm working in and I thought it would look good to include it. Would you mind showing the possibility with int[]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ArrayList` would be overkill for this. But if you must, (untested code)

First initalize your array to contain 13 elements (0 to 12) so that `IndexOutOfBoundsException` won't pop up. They would be initialized to zero.

```
results = new ArrayList<Integer>(13);
```

Then just get the element, add one, and set it

```
results.set(dicetotal, results.get(dicetotal) + 1);
```

---

Indeed, you should just use an `int[]` if you know the size of the array beforehand, and won't change during the program. They are faster than `ArrayList`.

```
// initialize
results = new int[13];
// could be new int[11]; if you put results in array elements 0 to 10.

// ...

// add to tally
results[dicetotal]++;

// or, instead, pack the array because dice roll results can only be in 2 to 12. 
// Put such results in array element 0 to 10, 
// by subtracting 2 to the index before putting in
results[dicetotal - 2]++;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Definitely helped.

Answer (score 1):

It would make more sense to store the frequencies in an array of integers. For one, it would be much simpler to increment the value for a particular result:

```
int[] frequencies = new int[11]; // sum of two dice can be 2-12

for(int i = 0; i < 36000000; i++){
    die1 = (int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1
    die2 = (int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1
    dicetotal = die1 + die2;

    // increment frequency:
    frequencies[dicetotal-2] = frequencies[dicetotal-2]+1;
}
```

Now your frequencies array has the frequency of the dice result of two at index 0.

Comment: the range `2-12` is inclusive, so the array should have 11 elements, not 10.

Comment: Yep. Was totally not paying attention there. Thanks, @luiges90 .

Comment: Array size must be 11 or he will get AIOBE when dicetotal = 12

Comment: @darijan -- Array size *is* 11. Perhaps refresh your browser window?

Answer (score 1):

Use a fixed-size array for 11 possible scores you can get:

```
int die1, die2, dicetotal;

int[] totals= new int[11];
for(int i = 0; i < 36000000; i++){
    die1 = (int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1
    die2 = (int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1
    dicetotal = die1 + die2;

    //just increment the right position
    totals[dicetotal-2]++;
}
```

Comment: I had something else in mind. Changed it after a few seconds, but you seem to have caught it. :)

Answer (score 0):

This may seem like an overkill but creating a wrapper for the counter so you can store it in a map will make the code a bit easier at the eys and easier to expand.

```
public static class Count {
    private int count = 0;

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void increment() {
        count++;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + count;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, Count> diceHistogram = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 2; i <= 12; i++) {
        diceHistogram.put(i, new Count());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < (1E+6); i++) {
        int diceOne = rnd.nextInt(6) + 1;
        int diceTwo = rnd.nextInt(6) + 1;
        int sum = diceOne + diceTwo;

        diceHistogram.get(sum).increment();
    }

    System.out.println(diceHistogram);
}
```

Outputs the number of occurances for each dice-combo.

```
2=28043, 3=55745, 4=83489, 5=110517, 6=138823, 7=166928, 8=138466, 9=111321, 10=83532, 11=55469, 12=27667
```